# Как остановить движущийся объект наведением курсора мышки на него, Python библиотека turtle

Tags: python, turtle

Прошу помощи. Python библиотека turtle. Есть нарисованный квадрат, который движется, не важно как, возьмем движение по синусоиде. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при попадании курсора мышки на квадрат, он останавливался, если убираем курсор, то квадрат продолжает свое движение. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать? Прикрепляю движение квадрата по синусоиде.

```
import turtle
import math

MyScreen = turtle.Screen()
MyScreen.screensize(500, 500)
MyTur = turtle.Turtle()
MyTur.hideturtle()
MyScreen.tracer(0)

def square():
    MyTur.begin_fill()
    MyTur.fillcolor("blue")
    for i in range(4):
        MyTur.forward(40)
        MyTur.right(90)
    MyTur.end_fill()

dx = 0.05

while True:
    MyTur.clear()
    square()
    x, y = MyTur.position()
    if MyTur.pos()[0] > 400:
        MyTur.penup()
        x = -450
        MyTur.pendown()
    MyTur.goto(dx + x, (100) * math.cos(math.radians(x)))
    MyScreen.update()
```

Comment: А хоть приблизительно есть идеи? Например, получать координаты курсора, сверять с текущим положением объекта, и на основе этого принимать решение, какую скорость ему задать.

Comment: Даже не знаю как это можно реализовать